# What would be causing this error in Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using expressjs and mongoskin to connect to the database and I have issues when throwing an expressjs error inside my mongskin call. I can't seam to trace down the issue as the error is so dang general.

My code:

```
db.collection('users').find(data, {limit:1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if(result) throw new noData('No results found');        
});
```

Error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error
    at /home/jmoney/workspace/blog/app.js:238:15
    at /home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:129:9
    at /home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:171:11
    at /home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:452:35
    at Cursor.close (/home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:660:5)
    at Cursor.nextObject (/home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:452:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:440:12)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:156:14)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:88:20)
    at Db._callHandler (/home/jmoney/workspace/blog/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1274:25)
```

Any ideas on why this might be breaking? or how get more in-depth error reporting?
Thanks guys!

Comment: try including the actual error message. The error message is probably `No results found`

Comment: You are using `result` in your function signature and `results` (_plural_) in your if statement.

Comment: @Raynos, this is all the info I get from node. When i toss the error, somehow it causes an error. cordsen thanks for noticing the typo, updated now, Mistyped it when i was typing up the example.

Comment: @Justin if line 238 is your if statement then it's the `No results found` error. I presume the reason it doesnt give any information is because `noData` doesn't inherit properly from `Error`

Comment: @Raynos Yeah i agree. Though id really like to figure out how to get node to dump out some more info on the error, more than "hey stuff broke, good luck" lol.

Comment: @Justin throw a real error rather then a noData instance

Comment: @Raynos yeah still causing an error, I wonder if mongoskin is somehow breaking things when trying to throw that error.

Comment: @Justin ... when you throw an error it causes an error. You are causing an error, the code works as expected, the result exists so you error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9695/discussion-between-justin-and-raynos)

Answer (score 0):

Never throw in a node.js function call unless you know what you are doing. There is no "stack" for the throw to unroll as it happens inside toArray. This leads to the exception becoming an unhandled exception.

The only way to trap that is using

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

log it to you logfile or or use console.log()/dir() or something similar.